# Why are my php pages loading so slowly?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, load

This has been frustrating me for a while now. I started developing a site for a friend using ajax to load content, but whenever the image galleries are loaded it takes soooo long. The annoying thing is that it wasn't like that when i tested it on my own server.

The test site is here: http://www.europeanbob.co.uk/phil/index.html

And the actual site is here: http://www.philmarsdenphotography.co.uk

The test is hosted on dreamhost and the actual one on krystal if that makes any difference?

Comment: Seems fairly responsive to me.  What size are the images?  What is your database scheme?  Are you doing any caching?  What are your SQL queries?  Are the tables properly indexed?  etc...

Comment: maybe a bit slow, but it isn't that bad. Probably just because the images are quite large.

Comment: They score almost the same on Google PageSpeed (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)

Comment: Site loaded in 962ms, it's very good

Comment: I see what he means, the gallery itself is slow

Comment: @LukePittman The images are only about 7kb each. Don't know about database scheme. Would that be mySQL? I've had to disable browser caching because it would not load new albums/news items. Looked into opcode caching, but i don't think i should need it with a db this size :/

Comment: arg whats wrong with KISS, why do people insist on such designs

Comment: You might just be really far away from the hosting server, which is adding latency for you, because it loads quickly for me.

Comment: If you could post the code for loading that gallery we could take a look at that. Might need some DB indexes if the table is big. Might be code that is not terminating correctly. You should also try putting in some before and after microtime() code points around code and code segments you think might be slow. Output that and you can find your problem child pretty quick.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some weird things, but [Stack Overflow is not a debugging service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/135066#135066). What I've seen from a cursory look at the network pane, when you click on `Gallery > People`, there are *two* simultaneous requests to `/inc/people.php` — one takes 4-4.5s and the other 8-9s, thus my guess is one gets locked waiting on the other to finish, which might be either due to session or database. These scripts return a bit under 4k, so the long delay cannot be explained by network latency — it is something you're doing server-side. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you have a lot of javascript and css files which all have to load before the image loads.

Every external file that you link to (ie non-inline file) requires a separate dns lookup and then retrieval.  The problem is that the browser will only look up a few at a time (a limitation of the TCP/IP protocol) and make the browser wait for those to return before looking up the next ones. 
The solution is to combine some of these javascript and css files from 8 or so to 2-3. This should shave off about 2 seconds